# SOAP Client Call Data Binding Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, soap-client

I am able to call soap service and getting the response from soap client does means connectivity is okay. But the request data values are not mapping to external system request. and we both are using same package and class names.

Please find the code as below:

```
UserListResponse response = null;

@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "UserList")
@ResponsePayload
public UserListResponse UserListRequest(@RequestPayload UserListRequest request) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Enters into UserList()");
    try {


       //Client call

       UserServicesLocator locator = new UserServicesLocator();
       UserServicesSoapStub stub = (UserServicesSoapStub) locator.getUserServicesSoap();

        response = stub.userList(request);//here the request data values not mapping at external system side

        } catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
        return response;
}
```

Note: Client classes are able to generated using wsdl and in that client classes having pojo structure with serialization and de-sterilization methods.

Can anyone please suggest on this issue.

Comment: What is this userService method? Your code for response should be something like this. resonse=stub.getresponse(request);

Comment: Yes, My bad.Please check now as i have updated my code. Thanks @Shubham Kadlag

Comment: What response are you getting? I mean any http error or custom error response.

Comment: I am getting the response as "getting request input values are null".When i print the request data values while calling it's displaying but external system side getting as null values. Thanks @Shubham Kadlag

Comment: Did you try calling service through soapui or any other tool?

Comment: from SOAP UI. Thanks @Shubham Kadlag

Comment: Did it work from SOAPUI ? How did you generate client? You can try generating client from wsimport/Axis2/CXF.

Comment: No, I am able able to print the request data but mapping not happening at client side. Any jaxb2Marshaller required before calling client method. Thanks @Shubham Kadlag

Comment: Did it work from SOAPUI ?

Comment: No, Not working. Thanks  @ Shubham Kadlag

Comment: What is the error in SOAPUI ?

Comment: No Errors, i am passing some parameters in request those are going null to external system and failing validation and getting the response as request params not defined in request. here question why values are going null to the external system even i am print the request data at my system and able to see before calling external system call. Thnaks @Shubham Kadlag

Comment: if get the same problem in SOAPUI then the issue is not of client but of the server.

Comment: is it possible to trace what is the request is going to servrer from client.@Shubham Kadlag

Comment: You can use burp tool to track the request